# ui-bootstrap columns break in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, row, angular-ui-bootstrap, col

I'm new to AngularJS, and I guess by default I'm new to ui-bootstrap. However, I'm no stranger to official vanilla Bootstrap, so I'm a bit confused why my columns are not aligning. For some reason, any size of columns basically just behave like rows unless I add "pull-left" or "pull-right" classes, but by default just breaks down. I have no idea why it's behaving like this, as I've seen other bits of sample code not having any problems with columns in this format. I've read all the docs I could find associated with ui-bootstrap, but there's no mention of anything regarding the Bootstrap grid.

Here's the Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/txDqsQHqLrmhrpS0Wyl9/
(I'm aware the menu doesn't work here, that's fixed on the local version of this project.)

And... this SHOULD work, right?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-4-sm col-4-xs" style="background-color: pink;">First Col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-4-sm col-4-xs" style="background-color: cyan;">Second Col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-4-sm col-4-xs" style="background-color: lightgreen;">Third Col
  </div>
</div>
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you verify you got all the right dependencies and versions?
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: The only one I left out was Angular-touch, but seeing as to how that's optional, I'm not sure how excluding that would effect Bootstrap columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:
The `col-4-sm` is incorrect. it needs to be `col-sm-4` the column width goes at the end.

Second:
If you are using angular material, I would recommend using the layout directives for controlling content position. See - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: I can't believe after using Bootstrap 3 for over a year now that I could botch columns with a simple flip-flop in code. I need more coffee apparently. Thanks Unknown.

I wasn't aware AngularJS actually has any kind of layout bells and whistles, I mostly chose it because I wanted to try making a SPA. So the Angular method is the best to go by versus Bootstrap's grid method? I guess I have some reading to do.

Comment: I personally would use the angular material directives as they offer a lot more flexibility for responsive design apps compared to the bootstrap classes.